# How to fix water damage on floor

Tags: water, floor, damage

how do I fix this space between wood and stone tile? Our fridge broke and water was on the floor overnight. This is how 5 months lost and the floor still looks funky.

I have no idea if the rest dried properly but seems to be no issue other than cosmetic aftermath. Is removing grout difficult / take a lot of time?

Here’s the image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_AyjqObLoguiRSCSx_slgVT1WRH7y1oU/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Remove all the old and broken grout and re-grout again.  Is that the only damage?  The sub floor and the wood floor was dried out properly?

Comment: Please use the site's own image hosting facility. [Edit] your question, click the "sun & mountain" icon then paste the image link in, or just drag the image into the text edit box. That way, others will be able to see the issue without an extra click, even after you've decided that pic is taking up too much space in your drive. Someone in the future will have a similar issue and want to look at it.